# Сложение чисел на ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер, nasm

Есть такая программа, считывающая два числа, складывающая их и выводящая результат:

```
    SYS_EXIT equ 1
    SYS_READ equ 3
    SYS_WRITE equ 4
    STDIN equ 0
    STDOUT equ 1
    
    

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov edx, len1
    mov ecx, msg1
    mov ebx, STDOUT
    mov eax, SYS_WRITE
    int 0x80

    mov ecx, numX
    mov edx, 2
    mov ebx, STDIN
    mov eax, SYS_READ
    int 0x80
    

    mov edx, len2
    mov ecx, msg2
    mov ebx, STDOUT
    mov eax, SYS_WRITE
    int 0x80

    mov ecx, numY
    mov edx, 2
    mov ebx, STDIN
    mov eax, SYS_READ
    int 0x80

    mov eax, [numX]
    sub eax, '0'

    mov ebx, [numY]
    sub ebx, '0'

    add eax, ebx
    add eax, '0'

    mov [res], eax

    mov eax, SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx, STDOUT
    mov ecx, res
    mov edx, 2
    int 0x80

    mov eax, SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx, STDOUT
    mov ecx, msg4
    mov edx, len4
    int 0x80

    
    mov eax,SYS_EXIT
    int 0x80

section .data
    msg1 db 'X=',
    len1 equ $-msg1
    msg2 db 'Y=',
    len2 equ $-msg2
    msg3 db 'X+Y='
    len3 equ $-msg3
    msg4 db 0xA, 0xB
    len4 equ 2


segment .bss
    numX resb 2
    numY resb 2
    res resb 1
```

Вот что показывает `objdump -D`

```
app:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

08049000 <.text>:
 8049000:   ba 02 00 00 00          mov    $0x2,%edx
 8049005:   b9 00 a0 04 08          mov    $0x804a000,%ecx
 804900a:   bb 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%ebx
 804900f:   b8 04 00 00 00          mov    $0x4,%eax
 8049014:   cd 80                   int    $0x80
 8049016:   b9 0c a0 04 08          mov    $0x804a00c,%ecx
 804901b:   ba 02 00 00 00          mov    $0x2,%edx
 8049020:   bb 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%ebx
 8049025:   b8 03 00 00 00          mov    $0x3,%eax
 804902a:   cd 80                   int    $0x80
 804902c:   ba 02 00 00 00          mov    $0x2,%edx
 8049031:   b9 02 a0 04 08          mov    $0x804a002,%ecx
 8049036:   bb 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%ebx
 804903b:   b8 04 00 00 00          mov    $0x4,%eax
 8049040:   cd 80                   int    $0x80
 8049042:   b9 0e a0 04 08          mov    $0x804a00e,%ecx
 8049047:   ba 02 00 00 00          mov    $0x2,%edx
 804904c:   bb 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%ebx
 8049051:   b8 03 00 00 00          mov    $0x3,%eax
 8049056:   cd 80                   int    $0x80
 8049058:   a1 0c a0 04 08          mov    0x804a00c,%eax
 804905d:   83 e8 30                sub    $0x30,%eax
 8049060:   8b 1d 0e a0 04 08       mov    0x804a00e,%ebx
 8049066:   83 eb 30                sub    $0x30,%ebx
 8049069:   01 d8                   add    %ebx,%eax
 804906b:   83 c0 30                add    $0x30,%eax
 804906e:   a3 10 a0 04 08          mov    %eax,0x804a010
 8049073:   b8 04 00 00 00          mov    $0x4,%eax
 8049078:   bb 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%ebx
 804907d:   b9 10 a0 04 08          mov    $0x804a010,%ecx
 8049082:   ba 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edx
 8049087:   cd 80                   int    $0x80
 8049089:   b8 04 00 00 00          mov    $0x4,%eax
 804908e:   bb 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%ebx
 8049093:   b9 08 a0 04 08          mov    $0x804a008,%ecx
 8049098:   ba 02 00 00 00          mov    $0x2,%edx
 804909d:   cd 80                   int    $0x80
 804909f:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
 80490a4:   cd 80                   int    $0x80

Disassembly of section .data:

0804a000 <.data>:
 804a000:   58                      pop    %eax
 804a001:   3d 59 3d 58 2b          cmp    $0x2b583d59,%eax
 804a006:   59                      pop    %ecx
 804a007:   3d                      .byte 0x3d
 804a008:   0a 0b                   or     (%ebx),%cl

Disassembly of section .bss:

0804a00c <.bss>:
    ...
```

Вот что показывает отладчик:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/rikitikitavi/projects/asm/app 
X=5
Y=5

Breakpoint 1, 0x08049058 in ?? ()
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, 0x08049069 in ?? ()
(gdb) info registers
eax            0xa350a05           171248133
ecx            0x804a00e           134520846
edx            0x2                 2
ebx            0xa05               2565
esp            0xffffd140          0xffffd140
ebp            0x0                 0x0
esi            0x0                 0
edi            0x0                 0
eip            0x8049069           0x8049069
eflags         0x206               [ PF IF ]
cs             0x23                35
ss             0x2b                43
ds             0x2b                43
es             0x2b                43
fs             0x0                 0
gs             0x0                 0
(gdb) si
0x0804906b in ?? ()
(gdb) info registers
eax            0xa35140a           171250698
ecx            0x804a00e           134520846
edx            0x2                 2
ebx            0xa05               2565
esp            0xffffd140          0xffffd140
ebp            0x0                 0x0
esi            0x0                 0
edi            0x0                 0
eip            0x804906b           0x804906b
eflags         0x206               [ PF IF ]
cs             0x23                35
ss             0x2b                43
ds             0x2b                43
es             0x2b                43
fs             0x0                 0
gs             0x0                 0
```

Как видно из `objdump` по адресу `0x08049069` находится команда сложения - `add    %ebx,%eax`. Перед выполнением этой команды в регистрах `eax` и `ebx` должны быть необходимые числа 5 и 5, вместо этого я вижу `0xa350a05` и `0xa05` соответственно. `05` на конце как бы намекает что регистры содержат то что мне нужно, но что за остальная часть? - я правильно понимаю что `05` - это содержимое регистров `al` и `bl` а остальное мусор? Тогда откуда он взялся?

Дальше я прибавляю код `0` к результату записываю в память и вывожу. Если при вводе вводить `4` и `5` то все работает:

```
rikitikitavi@rikitikitavi:~/projects/asm$ ./app 
X=4
Y=5
9
```

а вот если ввести `5` и `5` то все ломатеся:

```
rikitikitavi@rikitikitavi:~/projects/asm$ ./app 
X=5
Y=5
:
```

Мне даже понятно почему ломается - потому что в десятичной системе появляется второй разряд и прибавлять код `0` не совсем корректоно (Хотя результат в принципе правильный `:` идет сразу после `9` в таблице acsii). Нужно как-то подругому выводить результат, но мне непонятно как?

Теперь коротко вопросы:

1. Почему в отладчике я вижу какие-то непонянтые значения регистров?
2. Как переделать вывод результата?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вы копируете байт, в 4-байтный регистр `EAX` (а в нём лежит мусор). Нужно или непосредственно очищать регистр перед копированием, или копировать инструкцией `movzx` так:

```
    movzx  eax,[numX]     ;// zero + mov
    sub    eax,'0'

    movzx  ebx,[numY]
    sub    ebx,'0'

    add    eax,ebx
    add    eax,'0'

    mov   [res],eax
```

2. Чтобы выводить 2 и более разрядные числа, нужно делить число на 10 и прибавлять остаток. При этом каждый разряд числа выводится отдельно. Есть специальные процедуры, но в примере ниже это для DOS, а не линуха. В досе `INT-29h` выводит AL на консоль - замените его на соответствующий вывод для Linux. Процедура универсальная и может выводить в различных системах счисления, от BIN и выше:

```
;// Универсальная процедура вывода чисел на консоль.
;// на входе: EAX = число, EBX = система счисления для вывода (2,8,10,16).
;// на выходе: число в строковом виде 
;//------------------------------------
Hex2Asc:
    xor    ecx,ecx      ;// ECX =0, будет счётчиком разрядов числа
@isDiv:
    xor    edx,edx      ;// подготовка к делению
    div    ebx          ;// разделить EAX на систему счисления
    push   edx          ;// запомнить остаток
    inc    ecx          ;// считаем кол-во разрядов
    or      eax,eax      ;// повторить, 
    jnz    @isDiv       ;//  ..пока EAX не станет нуль.
@isOut:
    pop    eax          ;// берём очередной разряд из стека
    cmp    al,9         ;// проверить на DEC
    jle    @noHex       ;// если меньше/равно - значит не HEX
    add    al,7         ;// иначе: преобразовать в A-F
@noHex:
    add    al,'0'       ;// число --> символ
    int    29h          ;// вывод очередного разряда на консоль!
    loop   @isOut       ;// промотать ECX-раз..
ret
```

Comment: 1 - или переменные сделать не байтовыми, а двордовыми. "Вы копируете байт, в 4-байтный регистр EAX (а в нём лежит мусор)." - mov в данном случае копирует 4 байта, из которых на самом деле нужен только первый, в остальных лежат данные из соседних ячеек. Предварительная очистка регистра не поможет, а movzx - поможет.